# Difference between 'holdings' and 'estates'

Tags: differences

I am reading a table related to production of rubber; the title of the table is **Productions By Holdings And Estates**. In this context, what is the difference between *holdings* and *estates*?

Comment: This is not a definitive answer, but 'Estates' may refer to wholly owned properties, whereas 'Holdings' may be intended as a broader term for rubber-producing properties in which one holds a controlling interest.  Is there anything in the text to which the table is appended that might support this interpretation?

Answer (score 1):

Where is the table you are reading? Where does the document originate? If it's rubber, it may be about India?

In South Africa, a "Holding", or more properly, and "Agricultural Holding", is something between a farm and a town property, and can be used for agriculture, such as growing rubber.

An "Estate" has no legal meaning as far as property goes, but may be taken to mean an large contiguous piece of land made up of more than one registered property, but probably all owned by the same person/s or legal entity/ies, for a common purpose (such as, for example, growing rubber).

Comment: From India , the table belongs to a book based on rubber production in India

Comment: My guess is that it is about Malaysia. Both these terms are used there.